# Black edge around rotated transparent png in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, png, rotation, image, transparent

There are many working solutions to display transparent pngs correct in IE, but all these solutions will not work if the image is in a rotated container.

I' ve tried

```
img{
    background: transparent; 
    -ms-filter: “progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)”; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF); 
    zoom: 1;
}
```

to work around IE' s transparent png bug, but it does not work.

Ive created a show case at .
http://jsfiddle.net/s__a/Hmyc2/

Please be shure you visit this with **Microsoft Internet Explorer 7**, rotation is not implemented there for IE8.
Can anybody help to display the rotated image correct in **IE7**/IE8?

Best regards.

Comment: I don't know "bug" is the right description; lack of implementation is probably more accurate. The "black edge" I think you're describing is literally the lack of transparency; you're seeing the image without the alpha transparency mask. Can you post an http://imgur.com of what you're seeing? I'm using IE9's IE7/8 view, which is not always accurate to the real version.

Comment: [IE7 screenshot](http://imgur.com/0JzZH)
the uppercube is the correct one :)
I'm using IE9's IE7/8 view too.

Seems to me IE internal converts to 8bit if rotated :(

Comment: you're really pushing IE's capabilities with this sort of stuff. It's really not a surprise that it's not working. Seriously: ask yourself, does your site have sufficient numbers of IE7 users to justify spending ages trying to work this one out? Even with the bug, is it *usable* for them as things stand? If so, don't sweat it; just let IE7 users see something broken. If they're still using IE7, it won't be the first broken site they've seen. Maybe it'll encourage them to upgrade?

Comment: @Spudley I seriously asked myself. I definitely need IE7 compatibility.
If this will not work I will have to work around :(

Comment: IE7 ates time of the designers to spoon-feed it.

Comment: "Certain filters may not behave as expected due to how filters are implemented.  Filters work by rendering the content of their attached element to their work surface and then modifying that surface before compositing it to the output surface.  Because of this, alpha blending of a transparent PNG with non-binary transparency may lead to unexpected results." -http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/04/26/412263.aspx

Comment: @Spudley--cabapilities pushed further.

Comment: @axiomx11--Unexpected indeed, but not without capablity of being worked around.

Comment: @JaredFarrish--lack of easy implementation, anyway. Just took some working around.

Comment: @krish--yes, I spoon fed it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solid Background Only Solution Found

It took some digging around to piece it together. My first lead was [this site](http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved), which yielded the following change of code. *Actually, I just now noticed, what I have below is the same code you said **didn't work** in your question, but yet **it does for me***... recheck my fiddles and see if it works for you now. Note that in [this fiddle it worked for IE7 **but not IE8**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmyc2/27/) (the `img` does not rotate).

```css
.test-1{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFFFF,endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF)";/* IE 8 */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFFFF,endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF);   /* IE 6 & 7 */ 
    clip:rect(0px 276px 267px 0px);  /* top,right,bottom,left */ 
}
```

**So a little more digging** and a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055383/dximagetransform-matrix-absolutely-position-child-elements-not-rotating-in-ie-8) helped make [**a fiddle work for IE8 too**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmyc2/37/)! The IE8 final fix was that the item being transformed with the `Matrix` filter needed to have a `z-index` added in order to correct the bug of it not rotating the child `img` element.

**However, this "fix" is apparently still only a partial one.** [The issue on the rotated element](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmyc2/39/) remains at present for any transparency to the background itself, because if the alpha value for the gradient is set to transparent `#00FFFFFF` then it only functions on the non-rotated element.

Comment: Hello,
this is realy a good improvement. Unfortunately this will destroy the  transparency of elements. even the unrotated one. :(
I' ve added a background-image to demonstrate this. It does not work in IE9 too.

http://jsfiddle.net/s__a/Hmyc2/38/

Comment: @StephanAhlf--This was only intended for IE7/8, so conditional loading should be done for those (leave IE9 out of it). Now, as far as transparency, the hex value theoretically just needs to be changed to `#00FFFFFF`, however [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmyc2/39/) shows that it only works (again) for the non-rotated version. So yes, at present it seems only doable on a solid colored background (with the last 6 hex digits defining that color, in my original example, it is white).

Comment: @StephanAhlf--[That site to make it transparent](http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved) mentions doing animation of the item without issues to transparency, however, I did note that in the comments, one person said it failed in IE on Win 7 64-bit, which is what I am running. It would be interesting to find out if the rotated one is in fact transparent on another Win platform.

Comment: @StephanAhlf--It's a bit frustrating, [because the image and transparency is there](http://jsfiddle.net/Hmyc2/57/), it is just the way IE renders the surface below.

Comment: IE is frustrating :)
But it is nice to know thats possible on solid backgrounds. The team is working around by rendering a special IE7/8 version (simpler 8bit images).
However... You did it for the solid case.

Comment: @StephanAhlf--I'm glad you are getting a work around. Just as an FYI, more investigation has me convinced that the issue is in the `matrix` only having two `filterType` values ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532880(v=vs.85))). I don't think it understands how to properly handle the alpha channel with either of those methods to "define pixels of new content" that has been rotated.