# zoom css style is not applied to positioned absolute div element and it's children in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zooming

Below is html code for testing.
In other browser, all 3-divs are scale down by 0.5.
However in IE(including IE9), absolutely positioned div(second-depth div) and it's child div(third-depth div) is not scale down properly.

How do I apply zoom style for all divs properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="zoom:0.5">
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;background:red">
<div style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;background:black">
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (Not that this matters for the question at hand, but for your own understanding of the material) Is this HTML or XHTML? while the `<html>` tag would have us believe it's XHTML, the `<meta>` element screams otherwise, in two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

`zoom` is a non-standard IE property. Some other browsers (like firefox) will simply ignore it

The standards-compliant way of scaling an element is by using the `scale()` [transform-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

```css
body {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5);
}
```

Compare http://jsfiddle.net/tqMsv/ (zoom) with http://jsfiddle.net/tqMsv/1/ (scale)

Comment: Thanks!! your hint was very helpful! For the more information, I researched and found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055383/dximagetransform-matrix-absolutely-position-child-elements-not-rotating-in-ie-8/6268206#6268206

Comment: added z-index for absolute positioned div and progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix attribute for older IE works fine!'

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent elements style to "position:relative". 
Now all elements inside the zoomed parent element should be zoomed as well.