# Web Browser is compiling css elements in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

```
map.css({
    'zoom': zoom, 
    'left': map.width()/(2*zoom) - (point[0]/100)*map.width(),
    'top': map.height()/(2*zoom) - (point[1]/100)*map.height()
```

It looks like Chrome zooms our map then applies the left and top properties and IE applies to left and top properties and then zooms which lowers then left and top movements by factor of zoom.

Comment: Why do you think the order is important?

Comment: We have to process the zoom before processing left and top in order to properly place our elements on top of an image.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the browser at all. You are creating a JavaScript object that you pass to the css() function of jQuery. The whole expression is evaluated before that, so it will not be able to get a width and height of the element with the new zoom level.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling"? How did you notice that the order is different? Object literals are always interpreted in the same order as they occur in the source code.

Comment: @Bergi It looks like Chrome zooms our map then applies the left and top properties and IE applies to left and top properties and then zooms which lowers then left and top movements by factor of zoom.

Comment: Aha. Please [put that in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18852784/edit) to clarify it…

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

The order of CSS properties is irelevant.

```
elementA {
    propA: valA,
    probB: valB
}
elementB {
    propB: valB,
    probA: valA
}
```

Both elements have same CSS properties and are displayed equaly.

**Secondly**

CSS `zoom` property is not-standard and probably has an issue when used with positioning. A way of overcoming this problem is using `scale()`:

Compare [Zooming](http://jsfiddle.net/tqMsv/) vs. [Scaling](http://jsfiddle.net/tqMsv/1/) absolutely posisioned elements.<sup>1</sup>

`scale()`, however, requires browser prefixes:

```
.zoomed-element {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
       -moz-transform: scale(.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(.5); // IE 9
            transform: scale(.5);
}
```

Other method, a more IE compatible one, is to use an absolutely positioned container and apply zooming to the child [Zooming with container](http://jsfiddle.net/tqMsv/2/):

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; zoom: 2; background-color: red;">
</div>
```

---

*Footnote*

<sub>1: Fiddles borrowed from [zoom css style is not applied to positioned absolute div element and it's children in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270457/zoom-css-style-is-not-applied-to-positioned-absolute-div-element-and-its-childr)</sub>

Comment: @Jakrub thanks for the help but it didn't work fix the problem in IE and broke in Chrome.

Comment: Just a question, how the hell can the order of CSS properties change anything? That is just nonsense, you can move them around as you like (unless, of course, you apply the same property twice) and it is still the same. I think the problem is **elsewhere**.

Comment: @Jakrub It looks like Chrome zooms our map then applies the left and top properties and IE applies to left and top properties and then zooms which lowers then left and top movements by factor of zoom. Where else do you think our problem could be? Appreciate all the help I have been stuck on this problem for over a week and am extremely frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

var myFunnyZoomVariable = whatever;

```
map.css({
    'zoom': myFunnyZoomVariable,
    'left': map.width()/(2*zoom) - (point[0]/100)*map.width(),
    'top': map.height()/(2*zoom) - (point[1]/100)*map.height()
});
```

Comment: When removing zoom from map.css it zooms our overlaid element but not our map element. We reference zoom in multiple elements.

Comment: well, if you reference different zooms, then you might wanna put that into an own variable for each element a zoom is applied to. That's not nice, but should work if there aren't any other factors preventing it from that. But I also don't get why the zoom attribute has to be applied first. Anyway, I changed the code.

Comment: Our Code: map.css({'zoom': aZoom, 
         'left': map.width()/(2*zoom) - (point[0]/100)*map.width(),
         'top': map.height()/(2*zoom) - (point[1]/100)*map.height()

How IE reads it: <img id="map" style="left: -221.37px; top: -177.13px; zoom: 4;" src="images/17thmapwithextra.png"/>

How Chrome reads it: <img id="map" style="zoom: 4; left: -221.37px; top: -177.13px; " src="images/17thmapwithextra.png"/>

Comment: @user2788048: Is there any difference in the appearance? The order of properties in `style` strings is irrelevant.